# Why is my code displaying the wrong output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code that outputs "Yes" when the input number is a perfect number, and outputs "No" when the number isn't. But when I input 6, it outputs "No". I have specified it to print "Yes" with if-else statements when the sum of divisors equal to the original input. Why is the output wrong?

```
n=int(input())

myList=[]

for i in range(1,n):
    if n%i==0:
        myList.append(n)

sum=0
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
    sum=sum+myList[i]

if sum==n:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: `sum()` is a built-in function. Just use `sum(myList)` rather than write a loop to do the summing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion regarding my previous answer. The problem was that you were appending `n` instead of `i` in `myList.append(n)`. Moreover, you could simply use `sum` to sum your list.

Your output was wrong because you were appending the number `n` and hence when you do `sum=sum+myList[i]`, you were just adding `n` to the sum three times because instead of adding 1, 2, 3 to `sum`,  you were adding 6, 6, 6.

```
n=int(input())
myList=[]

for i in range(1,n):
    if n%i==0:
        myList.append(i)

if sum(myList)==n:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

A one liner suggested by [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209921/matthias)

```
print(('No', 'Yes')[sum(i for i in range(1, n) if not n % i) == n])
```

Comment: Just for fun (and to show the power of Python) a one-liner: `print(('No', 'Yes')[sum(i for i in range(1, n) if not n % i) == n])`

Comment: @Matthias: I am a fan of one liner but I guess the OP might find it confusing. Anyway, would you mind if I add your one liner in my answer with proper acknowledgement to you?

Comment: @Bazingaa: My comment wasn't meant as an answer. You can add it, but for a beginner it will be confusing as you said.

Comment: @Matthias: I added your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool one liner in comment section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608580/6360875)

other have already pointed out your mistake so here is how you can optimize your code a little bit.

greatest divisor of `6( =n)` other than 6 is `3( = n//2)` since we don't add number itself to `factors_sum` 
    while checking whether sum of factors equals to number( ie while finding perfect number),so we don't need to check whether any number greater than 3
    is a factor of 6 or not.

```
# perfect nums example 6, 28, 496, and 8,128
n = 8128
stop = (n//2) +1 # stop is exclusive thats why extra 1    
factors_sum = 0

for i in range(1,stop):
    if n % i == 0:
        factors_sum += i

print('Yes' if factors_sum == n else 'No') # Yes

'''
benchmark result( using timeit ran each five times)
for smaller value of n there is no significant difference but as the value of n becomes very large you can clear see the difference.
n = 33550336
1)    stop = (n//2) +1
      6.580396663 ( time in secs)

2)    stop = n
      12.635774489000001 ( time in secs)
'''
```